# How to draw a sloping oval with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I wanna draw a sloping oval with `UIBezierPath`. There is only a method `UIBezierPath.init(ovalInRect: rect)` to draw a oval without slop.What can I do to draw this? thanks

Comment: I guess that I can get a sloping rectangle first, then I can draw a oval with this sloping rectangle

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643928/draw-ellipse-with-start-and-end-angle-in-objective-c

Comment: What do you mean by sloping oval? Would you mind posting an image?

Comment: [image](https://github.com/Asahi-Kuang/picture/blob/master/oval.jpg?raw=true)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of a rotated oval:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // create oval centered at (0, 0)
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: -75, y: -50, width: 150, height: 100))

        // rotate it 30 degrees
        path.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 30 * .pi / 180))

        // translate it to where you want it
        path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.bounds.width / 2, y: self.bounds.height / 2))

        // set stroke color
        UIColor.blue.setStroke()

        // stroke the path
        path.stroke()
    }
}

let view = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.backgroundColor = .white
```

---

Here it is running in a Playground:

[image]